# Fscalenar selected event dot color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, fscalendar

I am using [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) for my application.  Can anyone tell me how to
set different dot color for only selected event ?

Comment: have u seen that gif image there. they have mentioned how to do that

Answer (score 1):

You have to set dataSource and delegate of calendar

```
calendar.dataSource = self;
calendar.delegate = self;

- (NSInteger)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar numberOfEventsForDate:(NSDate *)date 
{
    return 4;// Return how many dot to show below date
}


- (NSArray *)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar appearance:(FSCalendarAppearance *)appearance eventColorsForDate:(NSDate *)date
{

    return @[[UIColor magentaColor],appearance.eventColor,[UIColor blackColor],appearance.eventColor];

}
```